# C# Clear all items in ListView

Tags: c#, listview

I try to clear my listview but the clear method doesn't work:

```
myListView.Items.Clear();
```

This doen't work. When i put a breakpoint at this line, the line is executed, but my listview isn't empty. How come??

I fill my listview by setting it's datasource to a datatable.

My solution now is to set the datasource to an empty datatable.

I just wonder why clear don't do the trick?

I use a master page. Here some code of a content page when a button is pressed. 
The method SearchTitle fills the ListView.

Relevant code:

```
        protected void Zoek()
    {
        // Clear listbox
        ListView1.DataSource = new DataTable();
        ListView1.DataBind();

        switch (ddlSearchType.SelectedValue)
        {
            case "Trefwoorden":
                SearchKeyword();
                break;
            case "Titel":
                SearchTitle();
                break;
            case "Inhoud":
                SearchContent();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Method that fills the ListView

```
        private void SearchTitle()
    {
        // Make panel visible
        pnlResult.Visible = true;
        pnlKeyword.Visible = false;

        Search Search = new Search(txtSearchFor.Text);
        ListView1.DataSource = Search.SearchTitle();
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Is this Winforms or WPF?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

How about

```
DataSource = null;
DataBind();
```

Comment: does also work, but is similar to DataSource = new DataTable() (but yes, this is better i think)

Comment: yeah creating an empty DataTable is a waste

Answer (score 23):

Try this ...

```
myListView.DataSource = null;
myListView.Items.Clear();
```

Answer (score 7):

I did a search on this and I am using WPF c#. Just in case you got here too looking for a WPF solution use the following:

```
yourlistview.ItemsSource = null;
```

Comment: That's one way to clear it, yes, but if you null `ItemsSource`, it will permanently bar rebinding a `DataTable` to the `DataContext` of the `ListView` while that page is open.  At least it did for me. Better, in this case, is to set the `DefaultContext` to null. Then you can still set the `DefaultContext` to another `DataTable` later. If you use `myListView.Items.Clear()` like advocated in so many other answers, you get this exception:  `Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource, instead.`

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that `Clear()` causes a `Changed` event to be sent, which in turn triggers an automatic update of your listview from the data source. 
So this is a feature, not a bug ;-)

Have you tried `myListView.Clear()` instead of `myListView.Items.Clear()`? Maybe that works better.

Comment: The clear method on myListView doesn't exist:

Error 4 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView' does not contain a definition for 'Clear' and no extension method 'Clear' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView' could be found (are you missing a ....)

Comment: That is because we were talking about different objects, I thought you were referring to a 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView', sorry. In that case you should try what others already recommended: Set the data source to null first.

Answer (score 3):

```
listView.Items.Clear()
listView.Refresh()
```

/e Updating due to lack of explanation. Often times, Clear() isn't suffice in the event of immediate events / methods following. It's best to update the view with Refresh() following a Clear() for an instant reflection of the listView clearing. This, anyhow had solved my related issues.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged at SO. Please add an explanation.

Comment: I apologize - updated with a little more explanation. This solution had worked for my case.

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother with Clear(). 
Just do this:
ListView.DataSource = null;
ListView.DataBind();

The key is the databind();
Works everytime for me.

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is arising because you are trying to clear the entire list box.
Just use  `listView1.Items.Clear();`

Answer (score 2):

This is bit late, but this works for me at least using UWP

```
myListView.ItemsSource = null;
```

Comment: I also need myListView.Items.Clear() and myListView.ItemsSource = null;

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
myListView.ItemsSource = new List< DictionaryEntry >();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to remove the rows from the underlying DataTable, or if you don't need the datatable anymore, set the datasource to null.

Comment: How would you remove the rows?  `.Remove()`?  Should be more specific.  Setting the `.DataSource` to null was already covered in another answer that had been added previous to this one.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your code works but it is rebound somewhere after you clear it. Make sure that this it not the case. It will be more helpful if you provide some code. Where are you setting your data source? Where are you data binding? Where are you clearing the list?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the clear method is works like a charm. ListView1.Items.Clear() i think if its not working it may be the position whereby you place this code. Also can try nullifying the datasource.