# ListView.Items.Clear Not Working

Tags: c#, winforms

i am trying to populate listview on selection of node from treeview but every time i select node its get append in the listview my Listview.Items.Clear() function not working.
My Code:

```
listView1.Clear();
            if (this.treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag != null)
            {
                string msg = this.treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag.ToString();
                int complaint_id = Convert.ToInt32(msg);
                PopulateDataTable2(complaint_id);
                foreach (DataRow row11 in dsTreeView_Info.Tables["Complaints_Info"].Rows)
                {
                    listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem() { Text = row11["Complaint_Descriptions_Info"].ToString() });
                }
            }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435379/c-sharp-clear-all-items-in-listview

Comment: Have you stepped thru the code using the debugger..? if so what values are you getting when you step thru the foreach line..?

Comment: no. i am not using data-binding.

Comment: Change `listView1.Clear()` into `listView1.Items.Clear()` and set a breakpoint there to step through your code and check what `listView1.Items.Count` tells you.

Comment: thanks  DJ KRAZE. solved problem.

Answer (score 0):

i am not clearing the data-set after forecah. so it item keep adding.

```
 dsTreeView_Info.Clear();
```

Thanks " DJ KRAZE".