# why does my ListView still contain the old values from the table and does not refresh based on the query?

Tags: vb.net, oracle, listview

```
 listView.Items.Clear()

    cmd.CommandText = " select Item1," & _
                      "Item2, " & _
                      "Item3, " & _
                      "Item4," & _
                      "Item5," & _
                      "Item6" & _
                      " FROM myTable"

    gDR = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    While gDR.Read

        lstpenaltyview = listView.Items.Add(Null_To_String(gDR("Item1")))
        lstpenaltyview.SubItems.Add(gDR("Item2"))
        lstpenaltyview.SubItems.Add(gDR("Item3"))
        lstpenaltyview.SubItems.Add(gDR("Item4"))
        lstpenaltyview.SubItems.Add(gDR("Item5"))
        lstpenaltyview.SubItems.Add(gDR("Item6"))

    End While
```

everything looks good except that when I delete some stuff from the table, I still notice the old items in my ListView. I did clear it didn't I ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

These are the things that I'd do:

1) I will attempt to re-populate the listview AFTER deleting stuff.
or

2) [Try to implement a code like how the guy implemented a databinded listview:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435379/c-sharp-clear-all-items-in-listview)

Answer (score 0):

All I needed was "commit" at the end of my query.