# removing multiple list items from a listview

Tags: c#, listview

So I have created a button that when pressed it deletes the multiple items in the listview. However, I can only seem to make it delete one list item at a time. I know this is badly worded so my code should help explain what I am doing:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //remove
    {
        try
        {
            foreach ( ListViewItem eachItem in listView1.SelectedItems)
            {
                listView1.Items.Remove(eachItem);

            }
            task.RemoveAt(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index); // Remove task from the list "task"
```

I am trying to make it delete all selected items from my listview as well as my list named "task" However, the line of code above only allows me to delete one selected item from the list at a time.

Any help? Thanks

Comment: I have a list that holds items with multiple properties, the listview just shows the first property of each item in the list which is the title. It removes  selected items from the listview, I was just wondering if there is a way to make it remove all the selected items from the list itself

Comment: @Jamie1234 how about [clear the listview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435379/c-sharp-clear-all-items-in-listview)

Comment: I can delete multiple items from the listview, just fine using 

foreach ( ListViewItem eachItem in listView1.SelectedItems)
            {
                listView1.Items.Remove(eachItem);

It just, removing them from the listview does not delete them from the actual list itself. Its just "hidden" them. To remove them from the list I only know how to remove them one at a time using:

task.RemoveAt(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Index);

I am just trying to find a way to remove multiple items from a list at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your list of tasks is equal, in item count, to your ListView, and that the object in task[0] is the same as ListView.Items[0].  If that is true, remove the item from the task first then remove the item from the ListView

```
// Removing items from the bottom of the selected items and working your way up
for (int i = listView1.SelectedIndices.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    task.RemoveAt(listView1.SelectedIndices[i]);
    listView1.Items.RemoveAt(listView1.SelectedIndices[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This,

```
   for (int i = task.SelectedItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i++)
   {
     if (task.Items[i].Selected)
     {
         task.Items.Remove(listView2.Items[i]);
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (ListViewItem eachItem in listView1.Items)
{
    listView1.Items.Remove(eachItem);
}
```

Comment: You should provide a bit of explanation of your solution, pointing out the differences. That's the SO answers' style.

Answer (score 0):

you can only remove one item per line,

you can use the ".ToArray" extension method, if you are enumerating over a changing enumerable.

you should also use the BeginUpdate / EndUpdate function, to speed it up

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.listview.beginupdate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx