# Listview Item clear Issue

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using `listview.items.clear()` method in C# windows form application and then add new list view item.

It still displays previously loaded items.

```
listViewUsers.Items.Clear();                
dsUsers = aUser.GetUserNamesList(int.Parse(clientId));
int rowsCount = dsUsers.Tables["UserNames"].Rows.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
{
    dRow = dsUsers.Tables["UserNames"].Rows[i];

    lvi = new ListViewItem("item" + i, i);
    lvi.SubItems.Add(dRow["User_ID"].ToString().Trim());                  
    lvi.SubItems.Add(dRow["User Name"].ToString().Trim());

    listViewUsers.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

I have pre-defined columns in listview.

Comment: You are clearing "listViewUsers", but populating listViewCIUsers

Comment: sorry its a typo listViewUsers.Items.Add(lvi);

Comment: have you tried calling `Update` and `Refresh` on your listview after clearing?

Comment: yes. Tried Update and Refresh methods too. didn't work

Comment: @user1615089 How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/435528/3277813)?

Comment: Try a doevents, also make sure you are thread safe IE invoke/delegates...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Clear all items in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435379/c-sharp-clear-all-items-in-listview)

Comment: @user1615089 Try calling [`Clear`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.clear(v=vs.110).aspx) on the listview itself - `listViewUsers.Clear();`.

Answer (score 0):

Your can use the following code:

```
listViewUsers.DataSource = null;

dsUsers = aUser.GetUserNamesList(int.Parse(clientId));
int rowsCount = dsUsers.Tables["UserNames"].Rows.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
{ 
    dRow = dsUsers.Tables["UserNames"].Rows[i];

    lvi = new ListViewItem("item" + i, i);
    lvi.SubItems.Add(dRow["User_ID"].ToString().Trim());                  
    lvi.SubItems.Add(dRow["User Name"].ToString().Trim());

    listViewUsers.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

Comment: This works for WPF application. My app is still WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code will help you with the problem

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ListView listView1 = new ListView();
        listView1.Bounds = new Rectangle(new Point(10, 10), new Size(300, 200));

        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.LabelEdit = true;
        listView1.AllowColumnReorder = true;
        listView1.CheckBoxes = true;
        listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
        listView1.GridLines = true;
        listView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;

        var dsUsers = GetUserNamesList();
        int rowsCount = dsUsers.Count;
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem("item1", 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
        {
            var dRow = dsUsers[i].Name;

            lvi = new ListViewItem("item" + i, i);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(dsUsers[i].UserId.ToString().Trim());
            lvi.SubItems.Add(dsUsers[i].Name.ToString().Trim());
            lvi.SubItems.Add(dsUsers[i].LastName.ToString().Trim());

            listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { lvi });
        }

        listView1.Columns.Add("Item Column", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Column 2", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Column 3", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Column 4", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Center);


        ImageList imageListSmall = new ImageList();
        ImageList imageListLarge = new ImageList();

        listView1.LargeImageList = imageListLarge;
        listView1.SmallImageList = imageListSmall;

        this.Controls.Add(listView1);
    }

    public IList<ClientModel> GetUserNamesList()
    {
        ClientModel user = null;
        IList<ClientModel> listusers = new List<ClientModel>();

        user = new ClientModel();
        user.UserId = 1;
        user.Name = "Juan 1";
        user.LastName = "Donoban 1";
        listusers.Add(user);
        //////////////////////////////////////
        user = new ClientModel();
        user.UserId = 2;
        user.Name = "Juan 2";
        user.LastName = "Donoban 2";
        listusers.Add(user);


        return listusers;
    }
}
```