# How to clear a ListView?

Tags: c#, listview

I want to clear my listView if I have more than 33 items.

For this, I use the following code:

```
Console.WriteLine(listView1.Items.Count);

if (listView1.Items.Count > 33)
{
    listView1.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine(listView1.Items.Count);
}
```

I add items to the ListView with:

```
 foreach (DataRow row in dv.ToTable().Rows)
 {
     listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new String[] { 
         row[0].ToString(), 
         row[1].ToString(), 
         row[2].ToString(), 
         row[3].ToString() }));
 }
```

So when I put a breakpoint after *clear* I get at the *Console.WriteLine* zero. 
But after I add a new Item the Counter continues with 34. What should I do to set the counter also to 0?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Clear all items in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435379/c-sharp-clear-all-items-in-listview)

Comment: You need to set `DataSource` Null as `listView1.DataSource = null; listView1.Items.Clear();`

Comment: please show us how you add items to the listview

Comment: @SelimYildiz '''listView1.DataSource"''' doesent exist. I also tries Items.Clear() this doesnt works.

Comment: @SelimYıldız please check the documentation [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview?view=netframework-4.8). There is no `DataSource` property, you are mixing it up with `ListBox`.

Comment: @MongZhu with "listView1.Items.Add(new ListView(new String[] {row[0].ToString, ....

Comment: @NotYourFan please edit your post, this code belongs in there

Comment: " But after i add a new Item the Counter continues with 34." sorry cannot reproduce this, using your code I get a value of `1` when adding again items after clearing. Please post a copy pasteable code example to reproduce your problem. A piece of code that you could paste into a new WinForms project and see the effect right away

Comment: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)"

Answer (score 0):

set `null` to `ListView` Object and then bind it .. 
Try this :

```
listView1.DataSource = null; 
listView1.DataBind()
```

Comment: Yeah, this is typical mannouver, required by WinForms while data source change.

Comment: i use VisualStudio. When i write "listView1.DataSource" i get the error --> "ListView doesnt have Definition for "DataSource".

Comment: please check the documentation [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview?view=netframework-4.8). There is no `DataSource` property, you are mixing it up with `ListBox`.

Comment: @NotYourFan again: please post the code to show us how you add the items. and have you tried `listView1.Items.Clear();` ?

Comment: yes i try "listView1.Items.Clear();" --> it doesnt work.